# How to fix "NameError: name 'checker_start' is not defined"

Tags: python

How to fix these error code

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/erzajullian/PycharmProjects/Checker/topmail.py", line 9, in
>   
>       class checker_start(object):   File "/Users/erzajullian/PycharmProjects/Checker/topmail.py", line 16, in
>   checker_start
>       print(checker_start().get_token()) NameError: name 'checker_start' is not defined

This is the code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class output(object):
    pass


class checker_start(object):
    def get_token(self):
        data = requests.get("https://mail.topmail.com/preview/mail/")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "lxml")
        token_1 = soup.find("input", {"name": "form_token"})["value"]
        return token_1

    print(checker_start().get_token())
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line indentation of `print(checker_start().get_token())` is wrong. You are trying to instantiate an object of class `checker_start` and call its method `get_token` in the code-block(scope) of the class-definition itself. Therefore you get a `NameError`.

One of the most distinctive features in Python are code blocks with their indentations. In Python it is not matter of style (as in the most programming languages) to indent your code, it is a requirement.

> In most other programming languages, indentation is used only to help make the code look pretty. But in Python, it is required for indicating what block of code a statement belongs to.

**Try:**

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class output(object):
    pass


class checker_start(object):
    def get_token(self):
        data = requests.get("https://mail.topmail.com/preview/mail/")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "lxml")
        token_1 = soup.find("input", {"name": "form_token"})["value"]
        return token_1

# remove the line-indentation
print(checker_start().get_token())
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm a new on python, so the solutions is very simple, i think the error code on class. But in the last line, thank you i dont't expectate that!

Answer (score 1):

Your last line, `print(checker_start().get_token())`, is indented one level, and probably shouldn't be.